# When the database will be hit in case the repository method return a model object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have the following repository method:-

```
public RackJoin AllFindRackDetails_J(int id)
        {
            var tmsRack = tms.TMSRacks
            .Include(a=>a.Zone)
            .Include(a2=>a2.DataCenter)
            .Include(a3=>a3.Technology)
            .SingleOrDefault(a3=>a3.TMSRackID == id);

         var IT360Rack = entities.Resources
             .Include(a => a.ComponentDefinition)
             .Include(a=>a.ResourceLocation.SiteDefinition.SDOrganization)
             .Include(a=>a.ResourceLocation.SiteDefinition.AccountDefinition.SDOrganization)
           //  .Include(a=>a.CI)
             .SingleOrDefault(a2=>a2.RESOURCEID == tmsRack.Technology.IT360ID);
         RackJoin rj = new RackJoin { 

            Rack = tmsRack,
            Resource = IT360Rack,
            Technology = tmsRack.Technology,
            ComponentDefinition = IT360Rack.ComponentDefinition,
            Site = IT360Rack.ResourceLocation.SiteDefinition.SDOrganization,
            Customer = IT360Rack.ResourceLocation.SiteDefinition.AccountDefinition.SDOrganization

        };
         return rj;
        }
```

which is called from the following action method:-

```
public ActionResult Details(int id,string detailName=null)
        {
            var racks = repository.AllFindRackDetails_J(id);


            return View(racks);
        }
```

I know that in case the repository method returns IQurable<> then the database will be hit once I iterate over the Iqurable or call .list(). But what will happen in case the repository method can only return single object, when the actual data base interaction will happen?

Answer (score 3):

`SingleOrDefault` causes the query to be executed immediately. This is true for all LINQ-to-X extension methods on `IQueryable<T>` which return something other than `IQueryable<T>`.  For example `First`, `Count`, or `Max` all execute immediately.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. so in my example two queries will be send to the database ; one when creating the "var tmsRack", and the second when creating the " var IT360Rack". is that right?

Comment: @johnG, yes, assuming that RackJoin doesn't do any additional work in property setters or anything strange like that.